# Basic Android alarm app, Broadcast Receiver's onReceive() method not being called

Tags: java, android

I am working on an alarm app.  I followed the Android AlarmController tutorial word for word with only some minor changes.  For some reason my Broadcast Receiver's onReceive() method is not being called when the alarm goes off.  Here's the code:

```
// the callback received when the user "sets" the time in the dialog
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

         time.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay );
         time.set( Calendar.MINUTE, minute );

// Tell user alarm was set
String timeSetTo = "Alarm Set: " + time.get( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY ) + ":" + time.get( Calendar.MINUTE ) + " " + time.get( Calendar.AM_PM );
if( toast != null ) 
 toast.cancel();

toast = Toast.makeText( AlarmUI.this, "L" + timeSetTo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG );
toast.show();

// When the alarm goes off we want to send an Intent to our Broadcast Receiver (AlarmAction), 
// so set an Intent between the AlarmUI and the AlarmAction
Intent intent = new Intent( AlarmUI.this, AlarmAction.class );

// Create an IntentSender to have the intent executed as a broadcast later when alarm goes off.
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( AlarmUI.this, 0, intent, 0 );

/** Schedule the alarm */
// To get any service we use getSystemService( Service Name )
AlarmManager alarmManager = ( AlarmManager ) getSystemService( ALARM_SERVICE );
/* Finally, we set the alarm to the desired time! WOOHOO! */
alarmManager.set( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), sender );
        }
    };
```

Any ideas?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have your AlarmAction specified in your manifest?

E.g. `<receiver android:process=":remote" android:name=".AlarmAction"/>`

Comment: Thanx that fixed it.  So out of curiosity, what does "android:process=".remote" specify?  Also, the Activity is being called now but after it gets called I get an error saying that I should use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.  Would it be a good idea to create a new task everytime?

Comment: The flag I use for my pending intent is FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that if one already exists it is overwritten, to ensure I'm only dealing with one alarm at a time.  Once the alarm is fired I then set the next alarm if there is one needed.

I assume the remote attribute is required to so the process will launch privately outside of your application.. but not 100% certain.