# Why is Broadcast receiver's onreceive() method not invoked?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, smsmanager

I am a beginner in android development. I am trying to make a SMS scheduler app.My app's broadcast receiver's onReceive() method is not getting invoked? Given below is my source code.I have looked into some other links like [Basic Android alarm app, Broadcast Receiver's onReceive() method not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060919/basic-android-alarm-app-broadcast-receivers-onreceive-method-not-being-calle)Please,I would like to know where I went wrong.Thanks in advance.

1. Homepage.java

   ```
       public class Homepage extends Activity
       {
        public EditText get_number;
       public EditText text_box;
       public String search_string,text_box_buffer;
       public Bundle bundle;
       public Intent mesg_intent;
       public PendingIntent pending_intent;
       public AlarmManager alarmManager;
       TimePickerFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();

       public void showTimePicker(View view)
       {
           newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"timepicker");
       }

       public void messageSave(View view)
       {
           search_string=get_number.getText().toString();
           text_box_buffer=text_box.getText().toString();
           bundle.putCharSequence("number",search_string);
           bundle.putCharSequence("message", text_box_buffer);
           mesg_intent.putExtras(bundle);
           pending_intent = PendingIntent.getService(this,0,mesg_intent,0);
           alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
           alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,newFragment.getTime(),pending_intent);
           Toast.makeText(this,"SMS scheduled to be sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }


       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);
           get_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contacts_search);
           text_box = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_box);
           bundle = new Bundle();
           mesg_intent = new Intent(this,Alarmservice.class);

       }


       @Override
       public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
       {

           int id = item.getItemId();
           if (id == R.id.action_settings)
           {
               return true;
           }

           return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
   ```

   }
2. TimepickerFragment.java

   ```
   public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener
   ```

   {
       public Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
       public  int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
       public  int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

   ```
   @Override
   public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),this,hour,minute,DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
   }

   public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minuteset)
   {
       hour=hourOfDay;
       minute=minuteset;
   }
   public long getTime()
   {
       long time_ret = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+((hour*60*60*1000)+(minute*60*1000));
       return time_ret;
   }
   ```

   }
3. Alarmservice.java

   ```
   public class Alarmservice extends BroadcastReceiver
   {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent_local)
   {
       try {
           Bundle received_bundle = intent_local.getExtras();
           String number = (String) received_bundle.getCharSequence("number");
           String message = (String) received_bundle.getCharSequence("message");
           SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
           smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
           Toast.makeText(context,"SMS successfully sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           Toast.makeText(context,"SMS failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   }
   ```

   }
4. Manifest.xml

   ```
   <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="16"
       android:targetSdkVersion="24" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity
           android:name=".Homepage"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:screenOrientation="sensor" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
       <receiver
           android:process=":remote"
           android:name=".Alarmservice"/>
   </application>
   ```

Comment: and how does you manifest looks like?

Comment: try `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` instead of  `PendingIntent.getService`

Comment: @StefanBeike added the manifest file

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with creating the intent, do it like this:

```
mesg_intent = new Intent(this, Alarmservice.class);
mest_intent.putExtras(bundle);
pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, mesg_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```